# Scraping site to build currency exchange dictionary

Tags: python

I need to build a dict of currency to usd, it would look like this:

```
exchange_rates = {'USD': 1.00000,
                  'EUR': 1.32875,
                  'GBP': 1.56718, ...}
```

There are about 15 currencies I need to get and **I need to build this dict on a daily basis**. Has someone done this before, where they could show me the script they're using/the website they're scraping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this API: http://openexchangerates.org/documentation/

Comment: Great, thank you! And how would I 'read' the information? I'm trying to do `urllib2.urlopen(url); json=url.read()`, but it seems to lose its JSON formatting.

Comment: Just read this file https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json to the string using urllib as you suggest and parse it with standard json parser (http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)